# React Native Oppo A77 - Some texts gets cut-off

Tags: react-native, oppo

In Oppo A77 model, texts gets cut-off. This issue doesn't occur in Samsung, iPhone and other Oppo model. This happens either dev or production environment.

The screenshots provided below are just a few of the cut-off issues experienced in Oppo A77 model.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? I'm also having the same issue with Oppo R9s and Oppo R9st users.

Comment: no until now i havent solved this issue and it seems no one has an idea also :( this also happens in some LG phones

Comment: Did you try the suggestion on your issue on github? Others reported it working but I have not been able to test it myself. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114

Answer (score 1):

add space after the text is one of the solutions. You can also provide "Roboto" FontStyle to the text. as this issue appears only on the Oppo and onle plus devices which have default font style set which makes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space " " at the end of the text. This will fix your problem

Comment: add space in title of the navigation not resolving my issue.

Comment: try adding a fontFamily like below,
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: "Your Title",
      headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "Roboto" }
    };
  };