# Fonts getting cut down in react native on One Plus, Oppo etc

Tags: react-native, expo

I am facing a very rare and unseen issue that the fonts are getting worn out on some of the devices like the `One Plus`, `Oppo` etc. 
I don't know what's the reason behind that. But this is a device specific issue on some devices only.

Well, If anyone comes across the same problem I have the solution for them :

- Add a space " " at the end of the text
- Give the Text a set width.
- There is a proposed component at the bottom of the issue.

You can refer to this [react native issue link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114)

Also, this [expo link helps](https://forums.expo.io/t/text-cut-off-on-oneplus-device/4999)

But, my main concern is these all are hacks. Is there any rock solid answer to solve these things? Why to do extra work, why can't react native solve that? Or are there any permanent solutions to fix this?

[Please don't mark it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203809/react-native-oppo-a77-some-texts-gets-cut-off). I have the answer, I want to know the reason or any global answer to solve that in one go. I dont want to change all my 1000 text styles. :(

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114#issuecomment-335797756) is the answer

Comment: appreciate your efforts @RaviRupareliya. As I said I know the answers, I can ship the font on go with the project but isn't there any solution that should work without these? Shipping whole set of font only for one device while `robotto` and  `San Francisco` are considered to be system font by default.